# How to extract the datetime with optional microseconds musing patern matching

Tags: lua, match, openresty, lua-patterns

I need to come up with a pattern to match `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.s+Z` with the milliseconds part being optional. The regex is simple and looks like this:

```regex
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(.\d+)?Z$
```

Which match these strings:

```
"2022-04-02T11:24:59Z"
"2022-04-02T11:24:59.123Z"
```

In Lua, this isn't as straight forward as I thought. I've tried a couple of patterns but ultimately only got this one to work:

```lua
local pat3 = "^%d%d%d%d%-%d%d%-%d%dT%d%d:%d%d:%d%d[%.%d+]*Z$"

local dt1 = "2022-04-02T11:24:59Z"
local dt2 = "2022-04-02T11:24:59.123Z"
local dt_invalid = "2022-04-02T11:24:59.123.000.000Z"

print(dt1:match(pat3))
print(dt2:match(pat3))
print(dt_invalid:match(pat3))
```

That pattern meets most of my needs, but it's bothering me that strings like `dt_invalid` match too. I've also tried the following patterns with no success:

```lua
local pat1 = "^%d%d%d%d%-%d%d%-%d%dT%d%d:%d%d:%d%d[%.%d+]?Z$"
local pat2 = "^%d%d%d%d%-%d%d%-%d%dT%d%d:%d%d:%d%d(%.%d+)?Z$"
```

Lua has a simplified pattern matching functionality, but these patterns look more like the regex pattern. I'm not knowledgeable enough in Lua to know the difference or what I'm missing. Why does `pat1` and `pat2` not work? Is there a better pattern than `pat3`?

Comment: Since Lua patterns are not regular expressions, they are rather limited. One of the limitation is quantifying multi char sequences. You cannot do what you want like that, as in a regex. Either use a less strict pattern, or use two separate patterns.

Comment: `pat3` is incorrect as the plus is within the set brackets

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggesting to open a Lua Standalone and train yourself.
A very good tool for me is `string.gsub()` and every string has all string functions attached as methods.
That make things much easier...

```
> _VERSION
Lua 5.4
> ("2022-04-02T11:24:59.123Z"):gsub('^%d+%-%d+%-%d+%u%d+%:%d+%:%d+%.%d+%u$', 'MATCH ALL')
MATCH ALL   1
> ("2022-04-02T11:24:59.123Z"):gsub('^%d+%-%d+%-%d+%u%d+%:%d+%:%d+%.%d+%u$', 'Replaced with MATCH: %1')
Replaced with MATCH: 2022-04-02T11:24:59.123Z    1
> -- Lets replace "T" with a space
> ("2022-04-02T11:24:59.123Z"):gsub('T', ' ')
2022-04-02 11:24:59.123Z    1
> -- Cut off the last part
> ("2022-04-02T11:24:59.123Z"):gsub('%.%d+%u$', '')
2022-04-02T11:24:59     1
> -- Finally
> do local date, count = ("2022-04-02T11:24:59.123Z"):gsub('T', ' '):gsub('%.%d+%u$', '') print(date) end
2022-04-02 11:24:59
> -- Lets do a gsub() chain for all three cases
> do local date, count = ("2022-04-02T11:24:59.123Z 2022-04-02T11:24:59Z 2022-04-02T11:24:59.123.000.000Z"):gsub('T', ' '):gsub('%.%d+',''):gsub('%u', '') print(date) end
2022-04-02 11:24:59 2022-04-02 11:24:59 2022-04-02 11:24:59
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that in order for a set of characters to be "quantifiable" (eligible for a quantifier to be assigned to the set), you need to enclose the elements of the set between brackets.

In your `pat1` case, the last `%d` is not enclosed into brackets, so the `+` is considered as a character instead of a quantifier. On the other hand, in your `pat2` case, no quantifier will be considered at all.

Moreover in LUA you can't nest sets, so you can't specify a pattern like `[%.[%d]+]?`, cause it would match only the inside quantifier while the `?` will be considered as a normal character.

My solution would be to use a workaround that may be less restrictive (potentially prone to match other strings) still that catches the parts of the time you need:

```
%d%d%d%d%-%d%d%-%d%dT%d%d:%d%d:%d%d[%.]?[%d]*Z
```

Vulnerabilities (lines that shouldn't match - which match though):

- "2022-04-02T11:24:59.Z"
- "2022-04-02T11:24:59123Z"

Does this help to your case within the whole set of strings you have?